# Element not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, html

Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated (selenium)

I am attempting to make a betting script that follows the martingale betting style. Have tried many things like introducing wait times and messing around with the css selector and I get the same result.  Any help would be appreciated.

RESULT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users  line 28, in 
bet_input.clear()
Element in not currently interactable and may not be manipulated using python

CODE:

````
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

# Configure undetected ChromeOptions
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

# Create a new instance of the undetected Chrome driver
driver = Chrome(options=options)

# Open Chrome and navigate to the website
driver.get('https://rollbit.com/x-flip')

# Set initial bet
initial_bet = 0.50
current_bet = initial_bet
sleep(5)
# Main loop
while True:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 45)
    # Find the input field for the bet amount and enter the current bet
    bet_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-p16zna input[type="text"]')))
    bet_input.clear()
    bet_input.send_keys(str(current_bet))

    # Find the button for Heads or Tails and click it
    bet_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.css-ah57p3')))
    bet_button.click()

    # Wait for the result
    sleep(10)  # Or however long it typically takes for a round to complete

    # Check the result
   

    # If we won, reset the bet to the initial amount; if we lost, double the bet
    if 'You won' in result:
        current_bet = initial_bet
    else:
        current_bet *= 2```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should change the bet_input css selector to be like:

```
 bet_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-p16zna > input[type="text"]')))
```

in order to select a child element of class which is in this case the input